# how to do amazon SNS subscription confirmation and where it will sent the post request of subscription confirmation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, https, http-post, amazon-sns

I created an Amazon SNS Topic and added https subscription.
my problems are how to confirm the subscription.

The problem now is I cannot understand how to confirm the subscription for the HTTPS URL. I cannot see the post request where it is sending request. I am invoking this SNS topic by lambda function using javascript. can someone please help me to do it.
Thank you...

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscribe-https-s-endpoints-to-topic.html Do you think you could provide any information in your question about the HTTPS endpoint you are subscribing to the SNS topic?

Comment: yeah, I have created topic called vehicleStatusNo. and https://nextingo-dashbord-86244.web.app/ this is my endpoint.

Comment: i have subscribed to the topic (vehicleStatus) but it's showing pending confirmation. and I haven't received any  POST request from aws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From AWS documentation

> After you subscribe your endpoint, Amazon SNS sends a subscription
> confirmation message to the endpoint. The code at the endpoint must
> retrieve the SubscribeURL from the subscription confirmation message
> and then either visit the location specified by the SubscribeURL or
> make it available to you so that you can manually visit the
> SubscribeURL, for example, using a web browser.
>
> Amazon SNS doesn't send messages to an endpoint until the subscription
> is confirmed. When you visit the SubscribeURL, the response contains
> an XML document which, in turn, contains the element SubscriptionArn
> that specifies the ARN for the subscription.
>
> You can also use the Amazon SNS console to verify that the
> subscription is confirmed: The Subscription ID displays the ARN for
> the subscription instead of the PendingConfirmation value from the
> time when you first added the subscription.

To confirm the SNS subscription, you can perform the following steps:

- Log the complete SNS event in CloudWatch, which will allow you to access the SubscribeURL

C#

```
_logger.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(event));
```

nodejs

```
console.info(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))
```

- Identify the endpoint of the `SubscribeURL` within the logged event
- Manually access the SubscribeURL link in your web browser to confirm the subscription

Comment: can you please provide the code for that.

Comment: i am using lambda function to trigger the notification in js

Comment: Updated the answer with how to confirm the subscription